# Solve: $(x+1)^3y''+3(x+1)^2y'+(x+1)y=6\log(x+1)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve: $(x+1)^3y''+3(x+1)^2y'+(x+1)y=6\log(x+1)$

Is my solution correct:

Answer given in the book : $y(x+1)=c_1+c_2\log(x+1)+\log3(x+1)$

[image]

[image]

For my later reference: [link wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%20%2B%201)%5E3%20y%27%27%20%2B3(x%20%2B%201)%5E2%20y%27%20%2B%20(x%2B1)y%20%3D%206%20log(x%2B1))

Comment: How did you get the line after "(2) becomes"? Check it again.

Comment: @Moo Yes, I have found my mistake. I am not deleting the post so that I can refer to it in future.

Answer (score 1):

The $CF$ should be $(C_1+C_2z)e^{-z}$. The rest of your solution is correct and we finally find
$$y(x)(x+1)=c_1+c_2\log(x+1)+\log^3(x+1).$$

Comment: Yes, sir. Noted.

Answer (score 1):

Robert pointed out your mistake..

Here is another approach

$$(x+1)^3y''+3(x+1)^2y'+(x+1)y=6\log(x+1)$$
divide by $x+1$
$$(x+1)^2y''+3(x+1)y'+y=6\frac {\log(x+1)}{x+1}$$
on the left there is a derivative
$$((x+1)^2y')'+((x+1)y)'=6\frac {\log(x+1)}{x+1}$$
Integrate
$$(x+1)^2y'+(x+1)y=6\int \frac {\log(x+1)}{x+1} dx$$
$$(x+1)^2y'+(x+1)y=3\log^2(x+1)+K_1$$
Divide again by $x+1$
$$(x+1)y'+y=3\frac {\log^2(x+1)}{x+1}+K_1 \frac 1 {x+1}$$
$$((x+1)y)'=3\frac {\log^2(x+1)}{x+1}+K_1 \frac 1 {x+1}$$
Integrate again
$$(x+1)y=3\int\frac {\log^2(x+1)}{x+1}+K_1 \int  \frac {dx} {x+1}$$
$$(x+1)y=\log^3(x+1)+K_1 \ln |{x+1}|+K_2$$
$$ \boxed {y=\frac {\log^3(x+1)}{x+1}+K_1 \frac {\ln |{x+1}|}{x+1}+\frac {K_2}{x+1}}$$